# How to add dynamic loading text using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on an application that is currently consuming a lot of time to load pages, the only indicator for a user is a loading spinner which is added via a css class. I want to show the user that certain steps are taking place along with the loading spinner.
For eg.- Step 1 of 8...Step 2 of 8...

The code below shows the loading class, it works by attaching itself to the parent container of the page and thereby disabling the page.

```
loading.nq-button {
        padding-left: 2.5em;
}
.nq-loading.nq-button:after {
  left: 1.71em;
}
.nq-loading:after {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute!important;
  color: #53565a;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite steps(8);
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite steps(8);
  -ms-animation: spin 2s infinite steps(8);
  animation: spin 2s infinite steps(8);
}
.nq-loading.nq-data-table:after,
.nq-loading.nq-data-table-compact:after,
```

I've tried using a scope variable and incrementing its value after certain steps, but Angular does not update the scope variable when the loading class is active.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How are you initiating the loader?

Comment: using Jquery,--> for eg- pageContainer.addClass('nq-loading');

Comment: I think that may be your issue.  Angular and JQuery do not work very well together.  Jquery manipulates your DOM directly, where as Angular does not.  Angular cannot see the changes that JQuery does.  Rather try initialising the loader via a directive.